# How to return SUM of Column and COUNT of rows with GROUP BY in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I am not sure if my question has been solved earlier on Stack Overflow or somewhere, So I am quite sure that my question would be considered as duplicate, but never the less of all the solution that I found across the net, none of them served my purpose.

Question: I have a table

[image: Data Table]

I need to write a query which bring an output like below:

[image: Data Output]

The character column in the Output is actually the SUM of the total characters in the animal & vehicle column, and also I would need the total rows for individual users.
Thank You.

Comment: You must have certainly tried some query to answer this question.

Comment: Is this some homework? Or you're quite creative in obfuscating your data. (But I wonder, what if a user had, say six cars, but only one pet...)

Comment: Yes, I have should I post the best try of mine?

Comment: Hey this is not a homework, Since I have to demonstrate properly I made up those data in an excel.

Comment: Funny idea then. But next time don't make it up in Excel and post a screenshot, make it up as `INSERT` statements. That way people can use it to do test with the data.

Comment: @stickybit thank you for your suggestions. I will surely keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple `GROUP BY` with `LEN()` function :

```
select UserID,
       sum(len(Animal+Vehical)) as Character,
       count(*) Records
from table t
group by UserID;
```

Use `TRIM()` or `LTRIM/RTRIM()` function in case of *white* spaces there.

Comment: hey buddy.. it worked like a charm, and now I am seeing myself like a fool.. it didn't came into my mind to put the len inside the sum. thnx buddy.

Comment: @imcody Note that if you use `+` to concat 2 values, that when one of the values is NULL, the result will be NULL.  If you want to avoid that then better use [CONCAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_concat.asp).